# Alter Table add check for nulls and not nulls

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I am using Oracle Express, and I'd like to make a statement to add a check constraint to my `Invoices` table that allows `Payment_Date` to be NULL if `Payment_Total = 0`, AND `Payment_Date` to be NOT NULL if `Payment_Total > 0`.

I only understand how to alter a table to add a constraint that checks that a column's value.  I don't understand how to make constraints that Allow null values or disallow null values if a certain condition (ColumnValue > SomeValue) is met.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can express the check constraint:

```
alter table t add constraint ck_values
    check ((payment_date is null and payment_total = 0) or
           (payment_date is not null and payment_total > 0)
          );
```

Comment: I did not realize that I could express it in the check condition.  I thought that I would need to use the keywords NULL and NOT NULL outside the check condition as attributes, like the create table syntax. Thanks for your help!